# Type '{ children: string; exact: true; activeClassName: string; className: string; to: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Nav

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

Hello I am a beginner getting started with React Router -v^6.2.2, and generated the basic sources with create-react-app on template typescript -v4.6.2.

It works but I have this error on my console Visual studio code.

I have a problem on exact and activeClassName on the tag NavLink.

Error message:

"Type '{ children: string; className: string; activeClassName: string; exact: true; to: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & NavLinkProps & RefAttributes'. Property 'activeClassName' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & NavLinkProps & RefAttributes'. "

import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import '../styles/styles-pages/navigation.scss'

export const Navigation = () => {
return (


Home


Discution


)
}

Answer (score 1):

In `react-router-dom@6` the `NavLink` component hasn't any `activeClassName` and `exact` props.

[NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navlink)

> ```
> declare function NavLink(
>   props: NavLinkProps
> ): React.ReactElement;
>
> interface NavLinkProps
>   extends Omit<
>     LinkProps,
>     "className" | "style" | "children"
>   > {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?:
>     | React.ReactNode
>     | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => React.ReactNode);
>   className?:
>     | string
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => string | undefined);
>   end?: boolean;
>   style?:
>     | React.CSSProperties
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => React.CSSProperties);
> }
> ```

Remove the `activeClassName` prop from your links. If you still need to apply an active class then use a function on the `className` prop and access the `isActive` prop.

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import '../styles/styles-pages/navigation.scss'

export const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <div id="navigation_div_container">
        <NavLink
          className={({ isActive }) =>
            [
              "link_nav",
              isActive ? "active" : null,
            ]
              .filter(Boolean)
              .join(" ")
          }
          end // <-- prevents matching on sub-routes, similar to exact
          to="/"
        >
          Home
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink
          className={({ isActive }) =>
            [
              "link_nav",
              isActive ? "active" : null,
            ]
              .filter(Boolean)
              .join(" ")
          }
          to="/discution"
        >
          Discution
        </NavLink>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.
I understand better.